# Error al conectar base mysql con java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, mysqlconnector, mysqlconnector.jar

utilizo el siguiente codigo para conectarme a mysql

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  MapeadorServicio aux = new MapeadorServicio(); 
  Auto aux1 = new Auto(0);
  Persistencia p = Persistencia.getInstancia();
  p.guardar(aux);

}

 public void guardar(Mapeador map){
    if(map.getOid()==0) insertar(map);
    else modificar(map);
}

  private void insertar(Mapeador m) {
    int oid = proximoOid();
    m.setOid(oid);
    ArrayList<String> sqls = m.getSqlInsert();
    if (!base.transaccion(sqls)){
        m.setOid(0);
    }

}

public boolean transaccion(ArrayList<String> sqls){
    try {
        conexion.setAutoCommit(false); //begin T
        for(String sql:sqls){
            if(actualizar(sql)==-1){
                conexion.rollback();
                return false;
            }
        }
        conexion.commit();
        return true;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error en T:" + ex.getMessage());
            return false;
    }finally{
        try {
            conexion.setAutoCommit(true); //end T
        } catch (SQLException ex) {               
        }
    }

}

private Persistencia() {
    base = BaseDatos.getInstancia();
    try {
        base.conectar("jdbc:mysql://localhost/AutosYa.com", "root", "root");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Persistencia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Persistencia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Persistencia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

El error que tengo es el siguiente por consola

> Wed Dec 27 20:15:22 UYT 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   Error al conectar:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>       at mapeadores.MapeadorServicio.getOid(MapeadorServicio.java:46)
>       at persistencia.Persistencia.guardar(Persistencia.java:58)
>       at autosya.com.AutosYaCom.main(AutosYaCom.java:24)
>   /Users/usuario/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
>
> Error al conectar:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at mapeadores.MapeadorServicio.getOid(MapeadorServicio.java:46) at

segun mi MMAP

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui se ve como si puedo entrar con esas credenciales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi proyecto importe el JAR para el jdbl

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una solucion es que uses JPA para la conexion, es relativamente facil yo en mi caso lo uso con un framework que esta en netbeans que se llama EclipseLink y pues me va de maravilla. Como breve explicación JPA transforma las sentencias SQL en programacion orientada a objetos y pues nomas vas llamando a los métodos que necesites ya sea leer, eliminar, y actualizar. Investiga sobre el tema te facilitara mucho ciertas cosas al igual que puedes ir alternando entre JPA y JDBC que es el mas reconocido para realizar conexiones entre un gestor de base de datos y java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenos días:

¿Es posible que te falte indicarle el puerto MySQL en la conexión?, algo así:

base.conectar("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AutosYa.com", "root", "root");

Comment: Tambien lo probe y me da error , kabe recalcar que probe mi mismo codigo en windows y si anduvo correcto , por lo que me imagino que tengo algun problema con mi MAC

Comment: Hola @BrunoSosaFastTag  si no funcionó por qué se marco como respuesta?  :-|

Comment: @Jorgesys sinceramente no recuerdo pero seguramente esta resp me ayudo a encontrar la solucion